# Html.EditorFor shows the correct number of items but not the data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I'm trying to show ingredients of a particular ice cream on a create page.

I've got a viewmodel for the page which has a structure something like this:

```
public class IceCreamViewModel
{
   ...
   public IEnumerable<IngredientViewModel> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

*(there are other properties but they aren't germane to the discussion)*

`Ingredients` gets populated by the `Create` action on the controller and I've verified that it contains the data I want.

The `IngredientViewModel` has the following structure:

```
public class IngredientViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

In the Create view I have tried to display the collection of ingredients to allow the user to check which are in the recipe (e.g., peanuts, egg, etc.) and I'm doing something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Ingredients)
```

I've written and editor template for this that looks like so:

```
@model IceCream.ViewModels.Ingredients.IngredientViewModel
<div>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
</div>
```

What I'd expect to show up is a bunch of labels and checkboxes for each of my ingredients, but what shows up is the correct number of label/checkbox entries but they all say "Name" rather than the ingredient name that is in the IngredientViewModel.  So I'm certainly doing something wrong here.  It obviously knows that it has N items to iterate through but it isn't picking up the properties of those items.  Guidance?

---

**Update**

So, all I ended up doing was switching my `LabelFor` to a `TextBoxFor` and my values showed up... as they would, of course. (tired, long day) - `@LabelFor` uses the name of the property, or the annotated `DisplayName` for the property.  Things work fine now... move along, nothing to see here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a label for the `Name` property (as if you wanted the user to edit the Ingredient Name), instead of actually showing the name as the label for the checkbox.

How about changing:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
```

... to:

```
 @m.Name
```

Or, better yet:

```
@model IceCream.ViewModels.Ingredients.IngredientViewModel
<div>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
  <label for="@m.Id">@m.Name</label>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with `@m.Name` but what you wrote jogged my brain into using `@TextBoxFor` - thanks!

Comment: @itsmatt: No problem. Funny: I actually thought of that first and responded that way, but then when I read the question again, I thought you actually wanted labels instead of textboxes so I changed my answer.